# MySQL select data between two days which has php time() values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table and have datas like this

```
ID invoice_date amount
1  1392522748     58
2  1392486327     95
```

the invoice_date field store date value using php time() function, i need to get some datas,

ex - between two dats, monthly, yearly using mysql query, anyone know how to do that. thank you

Comment: what is the data type of invoice_date ?

Comment: Doh.... varchar... :(

Comment: thats a bad DB structure how ever you can use  STR_TO_DATE(), but I would suggest to use datetime for date fields which make life simple.

Comment: this is not a my creation,it was already done by someone i'm tiring to make few reports :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  PHP `time()` function stores as seconds since Unix EPOCHE.   If you're storing these as a string, you can convert that to a real date with  `FROM_UNIXTIME()`.  For example:

```
  SELECT * FROM tablename 
     WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(invoice_date) BETWEEN '2014-01-02' AND '2014-01-04';
```

Note, the `FROM_UNIXTIME()` will negate any index you have on `invoice_date` in the above example.

As noted in your OP comments, your best course of action would bet to convert the column to a proper `datetime` or `timestamp`.

Comment: @user2873965 No problem, just keep in mind the the impact on indexes if this table starts growing!